# How to update debian 6.0 squeeze at CURRENT moment (Sep 2016)

Tags: debian, upgrade

There are some manuals in network, but all think that debian still maintain mirrors for 6.0

However at current moment there are no squeeze on debian repos.

So how to update current server to something maintainlible if mirrors not availible?

```
apt-get update  
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main Sources               
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze Release.gpg   
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze Release
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/main Sources
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib Sources
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free Sources
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/contrib/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/non-free/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 128.30.2.26 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Debian Squeeze has reached EOL, it doesn't receive any **security updates**, but if you need to update your database and install packages, its repositories can be found on Debian Archive.

You should edit your `sources.list` as bellow:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main non-free contrib
```

Also you need to comment out all other repositories.

To update run:

```
apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
apt-get update
```

[debian-archive](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive)

> As time goes on we will expire the binary packages for old releases. Currently we have binaries for squeeze, lenny, etch, sarge, woody, potato, slink, hamm and bo available, and only source code for the other releases.
>
> If you are using APT the relevant sources.list entries are like:

> ```
>  deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ hamm contrib main non-free
> ```

> or

> ```
>  deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ bo bo-unstable contrib main non-free
> ```

Comment: I have added proposed sources.list, but i still get same error(now with "Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/squeeze//updates/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found")

Comment: That is issue. Debian, which claim it support for long time at current moment not able update itself. I have tried multiple mirrors,different. Same results.

Comment: @arheops Remove `non-free` keep just 2 urls

Comment: I found working only with this one line "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security squeeze updates/main"

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Squeeze is [no longer supported](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze).

To receive updates you must upgrade Squeeze to Wheezy, which itself is only in long term support, and thence to the current stable, Jessie.

Answer (score -1):

Even Squeeze LTS is unsupported now, but if you kept it upgraded while it was supported, you *should* have a system that can be upgraded to Wheezy, using the standard procedure, but it's probably not well tested. And Wheezy is only on long term support now, so unless you have very special needs you should go for Jessie, and it might just be faster and easier to reinstall.